# Dropdown list in wormhole

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js, drop-down-menu, ember-power-select

I'm trying to set the value of a dropdown list, that is located inside a wormhole.

This is the wormhole at pageload

HTML

```
<div id="ember-basic-dropdown-wormhole" data-identifyelement="27"></div>
```

once I click one of ultiple dropdown menus, the wormhole then contains all options of the dropdown menu.

```
<div id="ember-basic-dropdown-wormhole" data-identifyelement="27">                          
        <div class="ember-basic-dropdown-overlay"></div>
                <div id="ember-basic-dropdown-content-ember294" class="ember-basic-dropdown-content ember-power-select-dropdown  ember-basic-dropdown-content--left ember-basic-dropdown-content--below ember-basic-dropdown--transitioned-in ember-view" style="top: 296.0003776550293px;left: 815.0010986328125px;width: 187.000244140625px;">            <!---->
                         <ul aria-controls="ember-power-select-trigger-ember294" role="listbox" id="ember-power-select-options-ember294" class="ember-power-select-options ember-view"><!---->    <li class="ember-power-select-option" id="ember-power-select-options-ember294-0" aria-selected="false" aria-current="false" data-option-index="0" role="option">
                          --
/#/I want to access the following, without having to click the dropdown menu /#/
                        <li class="ember-power-select-option" id="ember-power-select-options-ember341-1" aria-selected="false" aria-current="false" data-option-index="1" role="option">Order</li>
                                <li class="ember-power-select-option" id="ember-power-select-options-ember341-2" aria-selected="false" aria-current="true" data-option-index="2" role="option">Agent</li>
                                <li class="ember-power-select-option" id="ember-power-select-options-ember341-3" aria-selected="true" aria-current="false" data-option-index="3" role="option">Status<li>
```

Any suggestion how can I access the "hidden" list or "only onclick to activate dropdown menu list"? If it is not possbile with js, may this be possible with brython?

Thank you

Comment: What is your use case? Is it related to automated testing?